# Remove duplicates from a list of a list of unordered dictionaries

Tags: python

Consider the following:

```py
[
  [
    {'name': 'fred', 'score': 19},
    {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
    {'name': 'bob', 'score': 99}
  ],
  [
    {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
    {'name': 'fred', 'score': 19},
    {'name': 'bob', 'score': 99}
  ],
  [
    {'name': 'bob', 'score': 99},
    {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
    {'name': 'fred', 'score': 19}
  ],
  [
    {'name': 'fred', 'score': 19},
    {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
    {'name': 'stu', 'score': 69}
  ]
]
```

Ignoring the order of the dictionaries within each list, how can duplicates be removed such that the output would be only two of the lists: one with bob and one with stu?

Output something like:

```py
[
  [
    {'name': 'fred', 'score': 19},
    {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
    {'name': 'bob', 'score': 99}
  ],
  [
    {'name': 'fred', 'score': 19},
    {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
    {'name': 'stu', 'score': 69}
  ]
]
```

Comment: only stu is unique and all other have a duplicate here

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: @AMC the issue was removing unordered duplicates, and yes I tried to find a working solution here and elsewhere before asking. Most all of them seemed to rely on the dictionaries being ordered. I'm still curious if there is a more pythonic way to do this than the answer I accepted.

Comment: @user13029880 Can you explain the operation to perform? More specifically, why should the output include both `"bob"` and `"stu"` ? To me removing duplicates means keeping only instance of each name, not removing the names who appear more than once.

Comment: @AMC Sure, the high level goal was to remove duplicates in the sense that order doesn't matter, and that the data within each list of dictionaries is the same for a particular 'name' (or ID).



Fred, Frank and Bob would be a unique group if disregarding order. The same with Fred, Frank and Stu. The others with Fred, Frank and Bob would be removed. We don't care which duplicates are removed since the data is the same within each dictionary in the list of list of dictionaries.

Comment: @AMC I also added an edit to show an example of the expected output to hopefully clarify a bit more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
dict_list =   [[{'name': 'fred', 'score': 19},
  {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
  {'name': 'bob', 'score': 99}],
 [{'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
  {'name': 'fred', 'score': 19},
  {'name': 'bob', 'score': 99}],
 [{'name': 'bob', 'score': 99},
  {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
  {'name': 'fred', 'score': 19}],
 [{'name': 'fred', 'score': 19},
  {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
  {'name': 'stu', 'score': 69}]]

# create list of names you've seen before
name_lists = []
# create lists of unique lists
unique_lists = []

# loop over each list you have
for L in dict_list:

    # get list of names
    names = [i['name'] for i in L]

    # check if you've seen this set of names before
    if set(names) not in [set(n) for n in name_lists]:
        print(names)
        # save these names
        name_lists.append(names)
        # add this list to your list of unique names
        unique_lists.append(L)
```

Output:

```
['fred', 'frank', 'bob']
['fred', 'frank', 'stu']
```

`unique_lists`
Output:

```
[[{'name': 'fred', 'score': 19},
  {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
  {'name': 'bob', 'score': 99}],
 [{'name': 'fred', 'score': 19},
  {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
  {'name': 'stu', 'score': 69}]]
```

Note that this method will save only the scores for the first set of unique names and discard scores when the set of names is duplicated. If it is expected that the same names may have different scores, you may want to save every unique set of scores. In this case, you can follow the method given by PacketLoss below:

```
name_lists = []
unique_lists = []


for di, d in enumerate(dict_list):

    # get list of name, score tuples
    r = [(i['name'], i['score']) for i in d]
    # sort tuples alphabetically by name
    r.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0])

    # check if these names and scores have been seen before
    if r not in name_lists:
        name_lists.append(r)
        unique_lists.append(dict_list[di])
```

Comment: In this case, what happens when a dictionary has the same list of names, but differing scores?

Comment: The OP did not specify whether the scores were important. The question was just about removing lists which contained identical sets of names. In this solution, the initial scores for each set of names is saved and the rest are discarded.

Comment: The question never asks for a check of duplicate names. `Remove duplicates` where the result would lead to only the lists containing `Stu` and one `Bob` would be included. Whilst you answer achieves the desired output, it isn't checking for duplicates as it is ignoring half of the equation. In the case OP runs this against real data, where the scores do not always match, you're not going to detect the duplicate lists correctly.

Comment: I acknowledged that your method will save every set of unique scores when the scores are different.

Comment: Thanks @EricM, the approach worked great for what I needed. All data would be the same in this use case, just potentially duplicated in a different order (poor design for another time :) ).

Answer (score -1):

Due to the ordering being off, a simple `==` will not match, we can work around this by gathering the data, sorting it as a list of tuples and checking if the match has been seen before.

```
data = [[{'name': 'fred', 'score': 19},
  {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
  {'name': 'bob', 'score': 99}],
 [{'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
  {'name': 'fred', 'score': 19},
  {'name': 'bob', 'score': 99}],
 [{'name': 'bob', 'score': 99},
  {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
  {'name': 'fred', 'score': 19}],
 [{'name': 'fred', 'score': 19},
  {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
  {'name': 'stu', 'score': 69}]]

seen = list()
result = list()

for idx, d in enumerate(data):
    r = [(i['name'], i['score']) for i in d]
    r.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0])
    if r not in seen:
        seen.append(r)
        result.append(data[idx])
```

With this method, we are checking that both the scores and names are a complete match, meaning if one score in a duplicate changed to `98` it would no longer be counted as a duplicate.

Output:

```
[[{'name': 'fred', 'score': 19}, {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100}, {'name': 'bob', 'score': 99}], [{'name': 'fred', 'score': 19}, {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100}, {'name': 'stu', 'score': 69}]]
```

Output with modifying scores in data:

```
data = [[{'name': 'fred', 'score': 19},
  {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
  {'name': 'bob', 'score': 99}],
 [{'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
  {'name': 'fred', 'score': 19},
  {'name': 'bob', 'score': 99}],
 [{'name': 'bob', 'score': 98},
  {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
  {'name': 'fred', 'score': 19}],
 [{'name': 'fred', 'score': 19},
  {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100},
  {'name': 'stu', 'score': 69}]]

[[{'name': 'fred', 'score': 19}, {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100}, {'name': 'bob', 'score': 99}], [{'name': 'bob', 'score': 98}, {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100}, {'name': 'fred', 'score': 19}], [{'name': 'fred', 'score': 19}, {'name': 'frank', 'score': 100}, {'name': 'stu', 'score': 69}]]
```